# Add a url parameter to the current post and read it in a shortcode

Tags: posts, permalinks, shortcode, url-rewriting, parameter

I am trying to add a parameter to the currently visited url but it doesn't work.
I've tried `query_vars`, `pre_get_posts`, `post`, `post_link`, `page_link`,`post_type_link`....
None of this work...

How can I simply add `&moo=$foo` to the url and read the `moo` value in a shortcode

Comment: It's not clear *when* are (or need to) add to the URL. You can add the URL during The Loop using a custom template. Or you can add it to a URL in the content with a filter to the content.   So, need more info on exactly what (and when and where) you want to do this.

Comment: @RickHellewell no I don't have custom template.

Comment: So exactly how are your trying to add the parameter? Where? Edit your question and show what you tried, and what you want to happen. More details will get you an answer.